# how to echo values from this array

Tags: php, arrays

can someone help me to echo [city] value and [country] value from following array:

```
<?php
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
    [uid] => 123456789
    [name] => First Last Name
    [current_location] => Array
    (
    [city] => New York
    [state] => New York
    [country] => United States
    [zip] => 
    [id] => 123456789
    [name] => New York, New York
    )

    [profile_url] => http://www.facebook.com/username
    )

    ) 
?>
```

thanks.

Comment: `echo yourArray[0]['current_location']['city'], yourArray[0]['current_location']['country'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array.  You want to try this:

```
echo $arr[0]['current_location']['city'];
echo $arr[0]['current_location']['country'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
echo $somearray[0]['current_location']['city'];
echo $somearray[0]['current_location']['country'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been pointed out, you have a multidimensional array - in other words an array inside an array.

This kind of data is usually accessed like this:

```
foreach ($yourArray as $data) {
    $locationData = $data['current_location'];

    echo "user id " . $data['uid'] . "\n";
    echo " - city " . $locationData['city'] . "\n";
    echo " - country " . $locationData['country'] . "\n";
}
```

So if more than one user appears in the data, you can handle each one.